# Cannot add standby database to the data broker configuration in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, errors, dataguard, standby

I have duplicated the primary database to standby database and then I added the primary database in data broker configuration. But when I'm trying to add standby database I'm getting following error:

```
DGMGRL> add database 'orcl_standby' as connect identifier is orcl_standby 
maintained as physical;
Error: ORA-16606: unable to find property ""
Error: ORA-16554: translation not valid

Failed.
```

Is this a problem with `log_archive_dest_state_2`? I have enable it.

Or is there any problem in DR2ORCL.DAT files?

Any help will be appreciated.